# Creating custom JSONEncoder

Tags: python, json

I'm running Python 2.7 and I'm trying to create a custom FloatEncoder subclass of JSONEncoder. I've followed many examples such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960516/python-json-serialize-a-decimal-object/) but none seem to work. Here is my FloatEncoder class:

```
class FloatEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def _iterencode(self, obj, markers=None):
         if isinstance(obj, float):
            return (str(obj) for obj in [obj])
        return super(FloatEncoder, self)._iterencode(obj, markers)
```

And here is where I call json.dumps:

```
with patch("utils.fileio.FloatEncoder") as float_patch:
        for val,res in ((.00123456,'0.0012'),(.00009,'0.0001'),(0.99999,'1.0000'),({'hello':1.00001,'world':[True,1.00009]},'{"world": [true, 1.0001], "hello": 1.0000}')): 
            untrusted = dumps(val, cls=FloatEncoder)
            self.assertTrue(float_patch._iterencode.called)
            self.assertEqual(untrusted, res)
```

The first assertion fails, meaning that _iterencode is not being executed. After reading the JSON documentation,I tried overriding the default() method but that also was not being called.

Comment: FWIW, `default()` is not being called because if the input is one of the types the encoder supports by default, it will not even look at your custom  method. Compare `lib/json/encoder.py`, in the definition of `_iterencode()`: The `_default()` is only called in the `else:` branch, after all known types have been covered. Therefore you cannot override handling for a known type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to round float values down to 4 decimal points while generating JSON (based on test examples).

`JSONEncoder` shipping with Python 2.7 does not have have `_iterencode` method, so that's why it's not getting called. Also a quick glance at `json/encoder.py` suggests that this class is written in such a way that makes it difficult to change the float encoding behavior. Perhaps, it would be better to separate concerns, and round the floats before doing JSON serialization.

**EDIT**: Alex Martelli also supplies a monkey-patch solution in [a related answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447287/format-floats-with-standard-json-module) The problem with that approach is that you're introducing a global modification to `json` library behavior that may unwittingly affect some other piece of code in your application that was written with assumption that floats were encoded without rounding.

Try this:

```
from collections import Mapping, Sequence
from unittest import TestCase, main
from json import dumps

def round_floats(o):
    if isinstance(o, float):
        return round(o, 4)
    elif isinstance(o, basestring):
        return o
    elif isinstance(o, Sequence):
        return [round_floats(item) for item in o]
    elif isinstance(o, Mapping):
        return dict((key, round_floats(value)) for key, value in o.iteritems())
    else:
        return o

class TestFoo(TestCase):
    def test_it(self):
        for val, res in ((.00123456, '0.0012'),
                         (.00009, '0.0001'),
                         (0.99999, '1.0'),
                         ({'hello': 1.00001, 'world': [True, 1.00009]},
                          '{"world": [true, 1.0001], "hello": 1.0}')):
            untrusted = dumps(round_floats(val))
            self.assertEqual(untrusted, res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't define `_iterencode`, define `default`, as shown in the third answer on that page.

Comment: I did try that as well but it's the same problem: the default() method is not being called.