# Python's json.dumps() adds many digits to floats

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format floats with standard json module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447287/format-floats-with-standard-json-module)

```
>>> import json
>>> foo={'bar': 0.2}
>>> json.dumps(foo, indent=4)
'{\n    "bar": 0.20000000000000001\n}'
```

Is there a way to have less precision/digits in the outputted JSON?