# Disable scientific notation in python json.dumps output

Tags: python, json, scientific-notation

json.dumps outputs small float or decimal values using scientific notation, which is unacceptable to the json-rpc application this output is sent to.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({"x": 0.0000001})
'{"x": 1e-07}'
```

I want this output instead:

```
'{"x": 0.0000001}'
```

It would be ideal to avoid introducing additional dependencies.

Comment: I'd hesitate to call it a "JSON-RPC" application if it doesn't actually understand [JSON](http://json.org/)...

Comment: or floats for that matter...

Comment: Your only choice is to convert it to a string. Will that work?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1447287/989121

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to format

```
evil = {"x": 0.00000000001}
```

is to steal `Decimal`'s "f" formatter. It's the only easy way I've found that avoids both cropping problems and exponents, but it's *not space efficient*.

```
class FancyFloat(float):
    def __repr__(self):
        return format(Decimal(self), "f")
```

To use it you can make an encoder that "decimalize"s the input

```
class JsonRpcEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def decimalize(self, val):
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            return {k:self.decimalize(v) for k,v in val.items()}

        if isinstance(val, (list, tuple)):
            return type(val)(self.decimalize(v) for v in val)

        if isinstance(val, float):
            return FancyFloat(val)

        return val

    def encode(self, val):
        return super().encode(self.decimalize(val))

JsonRpcEncoder().encode(evil)
#>>> '{"x": 0.00000000000999999999999999939496969281939810930172340963650867706746794283390045166015625}'
```

or, of course, you could move the decimalization out into a function and call that before `json.dumps`.

That's how I would do it, even if it's a lame method.

---

**Update**

Sam Mason suggests `format(Decimal(str(self)), "f")` instead, which should still always round-trip, but also produces shorter outputs.

Comment: about using `format(Decimal(str(self)), 'f')` instead?  I get a much more compact encoding with that, and Python already ensures that the float representation can "round-trip" back to the same float

Comment: @SamMason Clever, I like it!

Answer (score 1):

I can't find an answer to avoid the problem that converts `0.00001` to `1e-5`,so I wrote a `pretty_float_json_dumps` function. It works fine in my project! Hope it can help someone!!

```
def pretty_float_json_dumps(json_obj):
    dumps_str = ""

    if isinstance(json_obj, dict): 
        dumps_str += "{"
        for k,v in json_obj.items():
            dumps_str += json.dumps(k)+":"
            if isinstance(v, float): 
                float_tmp_str = ("%.16f" % v).rstrip("0")
                dumps_str += (float_tmp_str+'0' if float_tmp_str.endswith('.') else float_tmp_str) + ','
            elif isinstance(v, list) or isinstance(v, dict): 
                dumps_str += pretty_float_json_dumps(v)+','
            else:
                dumps_str += pretty_float_json_dumps(v)+','
        if dumps_str.endswith(','):
            dumps_str = dumps_str[:-1]
        dumps_str += "}"
    elif isinstance(json_obj, list): 
        dumps_str += "["
        for v in json_obj:
            if isinstance(v, float): 
                float_tmp_str = ("%.16f" % v).rstrip("0")
                dumps_str += (float_tmp_str+'0' if float_tmp_str.endswith('.') else float_tmp_str) + ','
            elif isinstance(v, list) or isinstance(v, dict): 
                dumps_str += pretty_float_json_dumps(v)+','
            else:
                dumps_str += pretty_float_json_dumps(v)+','
        if dumps_str.endswith(','):
            dumps_str = dumps_str[:-1]
        dumps_str += "]"
    else:
        dumps_str += json.dumps(json_obj)
    return dumps_str
```

Comment: Ty. I've edited a naming error and is seems it runs okay. Do you have any idea how this performs?

Answer (score 0):

This is supplemental commentary, not a complete answer for avoiding scientific notation in `json.dumps`.  With an extra round of parsing, the `parse_float` option on `json.loads` can help with some things, e.g.

```py
$ python
Python 3.7.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 19 2021, 16:07:37) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> data = {"x": 0.0000001}
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"x": 1e-07}'
>>> data = json.loads(json.dumps(data), parse_float=lambda x: round(float(x), 6))
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"x": 0.0}'
```

This only avoids scientific notation for small values that are rounded to zero.  While that is not efficient for large datasets, it can help in some use-cases.  This does not completely avoid scientific notation.

```py
>>> data = {"x": 0.00001}
>>> data = json.loads(json.dumps(data), parse_float=lambda x: round(float(x), 6))
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"x": 1e-05}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Such requirements should be formulated only for strings, as indeed this would require a custom float-like type if we wanted to keep a "numeric" (non-string) type.

But if you are ready to accept a string representation of floats, then there are dedicated tools for such customized rounding, such as `numpy.format_float_positional()`:

```
import numpy as np

my_dict = {"x": 0.0000001}

print("float:", json.dumps(my_dict))

print("float-like str:", json.dumps({k:np.format_float_positional(v, precision=7) 
                                     for k,v in my_dict.items()}))


>>> float: {"x": 1e-07} 
>>> float-like str: {"x": "0.0000001"}
```

Answer (score -4):

found somewhere on the internet

```
import json
from json import encoder
encoder.FLOAT_REPR = lambda o: format(o, '.2f')
```

after this

```
>>> json.dumps({'gps': [51.5, 17.5]})
'{"gps": [51.5, 17.5]}'
```

Comment: That does not seem to work: `json.dumps({'a': 1/2000000})` gives me
`'{"a": 5e-07}'` while the question was how to get rid of the scientific notation.