# YAML loads 5e-6 as string and not a number

Tags: python, json, dictionary, pyyaml

When I load a number with e form a JSON dump with YAML, the number is loaded as a string and not a float.

I think this simple example can explain my problem.

```
import json
import yaml

In [1]: import json

In [2]: import yaml

In [3]: All = {'one':1,'low':0.000001}

In [4]: jAll = json.dumps(All)

In [5]: yAll = yaml.safe_load(jAll)

In [6]: yAll
Out[6]: {'low': '1e-06', 'one': 1}
```

YAML loads **1e-06** as a string and not as a number? How can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable scientific notation in python json.dumps output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936554/disable-scientific-notation-in-python-json-dumps-output)

Comment: @SiHa That might be  a way to avoid the issue,  but the real problem is that YAML is supposed to be a superset of JSON and '1e-06` as you get out of the `json.dumps()` **is** a correct JSON number and AFAICT also a correct YAML number. PyYAML just doesn't parse it  correctly.

Comment: OK, was just a thought...

Comment: @Oren, I further updated my answer, as the oriiginal pattern I proposed could have a problem matching numbers without dot or exponential part. ruamel.yaml parses these JSON numbers correct without any additional patching.

Comment: @Oren just edit your yaml file from `1e-3` to `1.0e-3`

Comment: Hi @Koo the json was created automatically from a pipeline..

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that the YAML Resolver is set up to match floats as follows:

```
Resolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:float',
    re.compile(u'''^(?:[-+]?(?:[0-9][0-9_]*)\\.[0-9_]*(?:[eE][-+][0-9]+)?
    |\\.[0-9_]+(?:[eE][-+][0-9]+)?
    |[-+]?[0-9][0-9_]*(?::[0-5]?[0-9])+\\.[0-9_]*
    |[-+]?\\.(?:inf|Inf|INF)
    |\\.(?:nan|NaN|NAN))$''', re.X),
    list(u'-+0123456789.'))
```

whereas the [YAML spec](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2804092) specifies the regex for scientific notation as:

```
-? [1-9] ( \. [0-9]* [1-9] )? ( e [-+] [1-9] [0-9]* )?
```

the latter makes the dot optional, which it isn't in the above `re.compile()` pattern in the implicit resolver.

The matching of floats can be fixed so it will accept floating point values with an `e`/`E` but without decimal dot and with exponents without sign (i.e. `+` implied):

```
import yaml
import json
import re

All = {'one':1,'low':0.000001}

jAll = json.dumps(All)

loader = yaml.SafeLoader
loader.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:float',
    re.compile(u'''^(?:
     [-+]?(?:[0-9][0-9_]*)\\.[0-9_]*(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
    |[-+]?(?:[0-9][0-9_]*)(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)
    |\\.[0-9_]+(?:[eE][-+][0-9]+)?
    |[-+]?[0-9][0-9_]*(?::[0-5]?[0-9])+\\.[0-9_]*
    |[-+]?\\.(?:inf|Inf|INF)
    |\\.(?:nan|NaN|NAN))$''', re.X),
    list(u'-+0123456789.'))

data = yaml.load(jAll, Loader=loader)
print 'data', data
```

results in:

```
data {'low': 1e-06, 'one': 1}
```

There is discrepancy between what JSON allows in numbers and the regex in the YAML 1.2 spec (concerning the required dot in the number and `e` being lower case). 
The [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/) is IMO very clear in that it doesn't require the dot before 'e/E' nor that is requires a sign after the 'e/E':

[image]

The PyYAML implementation does match floats partially according to the JSON spec and partially against the regex and fails on numbers that should be valid.

[ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) (which is my enhanced version of PyYAML), has these updated pattern and works correctly:

```
import ruamel.yaml
import json

All = {'one':1,'low':0.000001}

jAll = json.dumps(All)

data = ruamel.yaml.load(jAll)
print 'data', data
```

with output:

```
data {'low': 1e-06, 'one': 1}
```

ruamel.yaml also accepts the number '1.0e6', which PyYAML also sees as a string.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is objectively a bug in PyYAML? Have you submitted a pull request fixing it?

Comment: @MarkAmery I submitted a PR for PyYAML last year that reintegrated the two code branches (Python2 and Python3) without any form of reaction That project is currently hybernating at best and I'm not going to waste my time on PRs for PyYAML until it reawakens. I later forked and went on with fixes (also some outstanding on PyYAML), because I had to move forward and could no longer wait. I think this is a bug, as it does not implement principle that YAML is superset of JSON nor the exact regex given in the YAML spec. With this change all existing PyYAML unittest passed when I tried.

Comment: @MarkAmery To be clear, I much rather had fixed the bugs that I did fix in PyYAML and then fork the source for the extra functionality (not acceptable to PyYAML) and kept the things in sync.

Comment: @Anthon Thanks a lot for your efforts. I am doing some scientific calculations with configuration in YAML. Having the possibility to write numbers in scientific notification helps a lot.

Comment: @MarkAmery and Anthon it seems this PR solves the issue: https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/pull/174

Comment: @cyberjoac Actually it doesn't. One should only apply those rules when parsing YAML 1.2 and not when parsing YAML 1.1. There are also no tests added in that commit that test proper behavior.

Comment: How did you draw the image?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to `ruamel.yaml`. Should be used now instead of PyYAML in the Python ecosystem IMO.

Comment: @SaddlePoint I too it from the JSON specification (linked in the anser) and put a simple alpha channel on it making the "outside" transparent.

Answer (score 28):

I think that

```
1.0e-1
```

or

```
1.0E-1
```

have solve my problem. And my code to read the yaml file is like this

```
import yaml


def read_config(path: str):
    """read yaml file"""
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        data = yaml.safe_load(f)
    return data
```

Answer (score 13):

I am new to using YAML so no idea on what is best, but writing either

```
1.0e-1
```

or

```
1.0E-1
```

in my YAML file has worked out-of-the-box. That is, have a decimal with the coefficient (without the decimal, I also got strings).

Answer (score 1):

In order for PyYAML to recognise this number format you need to write the base number as a float (e.g. `1.0`) and you need to add the sign to the exponent (e.g. `+1`)

These examples will work

```
1.0e+4
3.5e-3
```

Whereas these examples won't

```
1e+4
1e5
6.7e8
1.0
```