# Rounding float numbers within a dictionary

Tags: python, testcase

I am trying out a challenge at codewars.com, but I cannot figure out why my code cannot pass the test cases.I am supposed to round of any float numbers to 2 decimal points within a dictionary. I have done some research and found [Round off dict values to 2 decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145101/round-off-dict-values-to-2-decimals) and [Python - how to round down to 2 decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/python-how-to-round-down-to-2-decimals). I have also tested the code on my local PC and it passes all the tests. However, the third test case is a hidden test at codewars.com because codewars.com has two tests visible to the user but the code must pass three tests. I figured out the third test case from the message returned from codewars.com which is shown below.

```
 Basic Tests
    ✔ Test Passed
    ✔ Test Passed
    ✘ {'A':-17.200000000000003,'C':-47.200000000000003,'B':-32.200000000000003,
'E': 0.79999999999999716, 'D': 95.799999999999997} should equal {'A': -17.2,
'C': -47.2, 'B': -32.2, 'E': 0.8, 'D': 95.8}
```

The two test cases that are visible to the user at codewars.com are

```
test.assert_equals(split_the_bill({'A': 20, 'B': 15, 'C': 10}), {'A': 5, 'B': 0, 'C': -5})
test.assert_equals(split_the_bill({'A': 40, 'B': 25, 'X': 10}), {'A': 15, 'B': 0, 'X': -15})
```

My code and testcases that I have used to test the same code are shown below

```
from statistics import mean
import unittest
import math
##############  My Code ####################################################
def split_the_bill(x):
    keys = list(x.values())
    keys2 = list(x.keys())
    average = mean(keys)
    keys3 = [(math.ceil((i-average)*100)/100) if type(i) == float else (i-average) for i in keys]
    ans = dict( zip( keys2, keys3))

    return ans

######################### My Test Case ###########################
class MyTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        new_string = split_the_bill({'A': 20, 'B': 15, 'C': 10})
        self.assertEqual(new_string, {'A': 5, 'B': 0, 'C': -5},
                         msg = "should return {'A': 5, 'B': 0, 'C': -5}")
    def test1(self):
        new_string = split_the_bill({'A': 40, 'B': 25, 'X': 10})
        self.assertEqual(new_string, {'A': 15, 'B': 0, 'X': -15},
                         msg = "should return {'A': 15, 'B': 0, 'X': -15}")

    def test2(self):
        new_string = split_the_bill({'A': -17.200000000000003, 'C': -47.200000000000003, 'B': -32.200000000000003, 'E': 0.79999999999999716, 'D': 95.799999999999997})
        self.assertEqual(new_string, {'A': -17.2, 'C': -47.2, 'B': -32.2, 'E': 0.8, 'D': 95.8},
                         msg = "should return {'A': -17.2, 'C': -47.2, 'B': -32.2, 'E': 0.8, 'D': 95.8}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Extensive instructions for the challenge can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/GRkhjriz). Kindly help me identify why my code cannot pass the hidden test. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run your code and it works. Maybe you can try to use `round` to round the floating number into any decimal as following:

```
def split_the_bill(x):
    keys = list(x.values())
    keys2 = list(x.keys())
    average = mean(keys)
    keys3 = [(round(i-average, 1)) for i in keys]
    ans = dict( zip( keys2, keys3))
    return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

here it works ! many thanks for your sharing mate :)

```
def split_the_bill(x):
    keys = list(x.values())
    keys2 = list(x.keys())
    average = sum(keys) / len(keys)
    keys3 = [(round(i-average, 2)) for i in keys]
    ans = dict( zip( keys2, keys3))
    return ans
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33693104)