# Floats in JSON on GAE / gviz_api

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

I have a python application running on Google App Engines which outputs data in JSON format structured by the gviz_api for Google Charts visualisation. The code is as follows:

```
class StatsItem(ndb.Model):
    added      = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True, verbose_name = "Upload date")
    originated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(verbose_name = "Origination date")
    host       = ndb.StringProperty(verbose_name = "Originating host")
    uptime     = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed = False, verbose_name = "Uptime")
    load1      = ndb.FloatProperty(indexed = False, verbose_name = "1-min load")
    load5      = ndb.FloatProperty(indexed = False, verbose_name = "5-min load")
    load15     = ndb.FloatProperty(indexed = False, verbose_name = "15-min load")

class ChartDataPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        span = int(self.request.get('span', 720))
        stats = StatsItem.query().order(-StatsItem.originated).fetch(span)

        header = { 'originated' : ("datetime", "date") }

        vars = []
        for v in self.request.get_all('v'):
            if v in StatsItem._properties.keys():
                vars.append(v)
                header[v] = ("number", StatsItem._properties[v]._verbose_name)

        data = []
        for s in stats:
            entry = { 'originated' : s.originated }
            for v in vars:
                entry[v] = getattr(s, v)
            data.append(entry)

        data_table = gviz_api.DataTable(header)
        data_table.LoadData(data)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        self.response.out.write(data_table.ToJSonResponse(columns_order=(("originated",) + tuple(vars)),
                                                          order_by="originated"))
```

It is working all right, but I get the famous issue with float-type properties, namely this is the output I am seeing (example):

> google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"status":"ok","table":{"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,11,19,12,55,22,460)"},{"v":0.33000000000000002}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,11,19,12,56,22,641)"},{"v":0.33000000000000002}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,11,19,12,57,22,747)"},{"v":0.28999999999999998}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,11,19,12,58,22,914)"},{"v":0.25}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,11,19,12,59,23,19)"},{"v":0.28000000000000003}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,11,19,13,0,23,169)"},{"v":0.28000000000000003}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,11,19,13,1,23,268)"},{"v":0.41999999999999998}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,11,19,13,2,23,385)"},{"v":0.40999999999999998}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,11,19,13,3,23,518)"},{"v":0.40999999999999998}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013,11,19,13,4,23,643)"},{"v":0.40999999999999998}]}],"cols":[{"type":"datetime","id":"originated","label":"date"},{"type":"number","id":"load5","label":"5-min load"}]},"reqId":"0","version":"0.6"});

So a float with a value of 0.33 (as seen in the DataStore viewer) is represented as 0.33000000000000002 in JSON. While it works, this is not only ugly, but also takes up bandwidth, so I would like to round it to 2 digits, i.e. 0.33. Strangely enough in some cases, this is happening (see 0.25 above).

I am loading the gviz_api module from my applications directory.

I have tried the following solutions, none of these worked:

1. round()-ing the figure before inputting into the datatable (round(getattr(s, v)) in the above code). It gets invoked, as I see integers turning into floats, but has no impact on the above issue with floats.
2. [Monkey-patching JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1447581/3084386) both in the GAE application module and also in the gviz_api module. No effect, the code is just simply not invoked, as if it was not there at all.
3. Overriding the default() method in gviz_api.DataTableJSONEncoder. This is not working I guess because it gets invoked only for unknown data types.

I have not tried yet to process the JSON string produced with regexps and I would like to avoid that if possible. Any ideas how to fix it?