# json.encoder.FLOAT_REPR changed but no effect

Tags: python, limit, precision

I am trying to make my JSON encoder dump floats with only 2 decimal precision. So '2.241' becomes '2.24'

I've read in [this answer by Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1447581/5324953) that you can overwrite the default FLOAT_REPR of json.encoder. I have tried the following:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.encoder.FLOAT_REPR = lambda o: format(o, '.2f')
```

But I dont get the same results:

```
>>> json.dumps(2.241)
'2.241'
```

And I can even verify the FLOAT_REPR is changed:

```
>>> print json.encoder.FLOAT_REPR
<function <lambda> at 0xb....>
```

And works as expected:

```
>>> json.encoder.FLOAT_REPR(2.241)
2.24
```

Why is the built-in JSON module not using the FLOAT_REPR when I can see that it has been overwritten and the solution should be working according to Alex Martelli?

I have tested this on two different computers, both running Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.0.4.

Comment: I found a comment in the mentioned question stating that "onkey patching json.encoder.FLOAT_REPR does not work if your Python runtime uses a C version of the JSON module" this can explain why it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs beause of the CPython speedups done by the `c_make_encoder` in `json.encoder`.

If you set it to `None` then the `json.encoder.FLOAT_REPR` trick works
as explained in this answer on the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1645929/5324953):

> The monkey-patch trick does not seem to work with the original
>   simplejson module if the C speedups are installed:

My implementation can be seen in the [jsonplustypes repository](https://github.com/sloev/jsonplustypes/blob/master/python/jsonplustypes/__init__.py).

Note: This solution doesn't work on python 3.6+

Comment: Btw this "problem" exist both in builtin json and simplejson due to similar c speedup implementation

Comment: Not working in Python 3.6.

Comment: edited the post to add the info and to bump the question.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer try this answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447287/format-floats-with-standard-json-module: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733105/6451573

Comment: For a simple monkey-patch solution that works with Python 3, see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370322/