# write json float in scientific notation

Tags: python, json, python-3.6

I would like to represent floats in a JSON file in scientific notation using Python 3.6+. None of

```
import json

a = 0.001234567

print(json.dumps(a))

json.encoder.FLOAT_REPR = lambda x: "{:e}".format(x)
print(json.dumps(a))

json.encoder.c_make_encoder = None
json.encoder.FLOAT_REPR = lambda x: "{:e}".format(x)
print(json.dumps(a))
```

work: All three `print`s give

```
0.001234567
```

instead of the desired

```
1.234567e-03
```

(Note that the last version works at least in in Python 2.7.15rc1.)

The answer should work with lists of `float`s as well.

Any hints?

Comment: The question is now marked as "Already has an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32521823/python-json-encoder-float-repr-changed-but-no-effect", but that answer does _not_ work.

Comment: seems that we have to find an answer for python 3.6. there's no need to open another question, though.

Comment: an answer in an original question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733105/6451573 no monkey patching, worth a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I created my own json library that can format floats, [fjson](https://github.com/nschloe/fjson). Install with

```
pip install fjson
```

and use as

```
import math
import fjson


data = {"a": 1, "b": math.pi}
string = fjson.dumps(data, float_format=".6e", indent=2, separators=(", ", ": "))
print(string)
```

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 3.141593e+00
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add some special casing for dicts, lists, sets, etc., but by referencing abstract base classes from `collections.abc`, you avoid explicitly testing for specific types.

Note that the test for `Sequence` has to avoid matching on `str` types, since iterating over a `str` gives a bunch of 1-character `str`s, which are also iterable `Sequence`s, and so on until you reach the recursion limit. I could not find an ABC that represents "a sequence container, but not a str".

(I also have to echo Alex Martelli's criticism from a related post, that having to do this much work just to format a particular type speaks to issues in the design of the classes in this module.)

```
import json
from collections.abc import Mapping, Sequence

a = 0.001234567

class ScientificNotationEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def iterencode(self, o, _one_shot=False):
        if isinstance(o, float):
            return "{:e}".format(o)
        elif isinstance(o, Mapping):
            return "{{{}}}".format(', '.join('"{}" : {}'.format(str(ok), self.iterencode(ov))
                                             for ok, ov in o.items()))
        elif isinstance(o, Sequence) and not isinstance(o, str):
            return "[{}]".format(', '.join(map(self.iterencode, o)))
        return ', '.join(super().iterencode(o, _one_shot))

aout = json.dumps([a, a, "xyzzy", 42, {'z': a}, (a, a, a),],
                  cls=ScientificNotationEncoder)
print(aout)

# loading back in seems to still work okay!
print(json.loads(aout))
```

Prints:

```
[1.234567e-03, 1.234567e-03, "xyzzy", 42, {"z" : 1.234567e-03}, [1.234567e-03, 1.234567e-03, 1.234567e-03]]
[0.001234567, 0.001234567, 'xyzzy', 42, {'z': 0.001234567}, [0.001234567, 0.001234567, 0.001234567]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This only works when converting a _single_ float. Put in `[a, a]` and it won't work.

Comment: Not working for dicts à la `{"key": 0.00123}` now. This will probably be an uphill battle if all cases have to be listed separately.

Comment: Maybe not so terrible if you can use abstract types from `collections.abc`

Comment: Discussion on meta about your reopening: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369085/4909087

Comment: this code of this answer looks slightly superior to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733105/6451573 which should be the original question for this question. I think it would make better sense if it was posted there, and with a little more explanation.