# Decimal class rounding in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, decimal

i have problems rounding `Decimals()` inside a Pandas Dataframe. The `round()` method does not work and using `quantize()` neither. I've searched for a solution  with no luck so far.

`round()` does nothing, i asume it is meant for float numbers

`quantize()` won't work because it is not a DataFrame function

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you post the error message and dataframe example. It would help us find an answer for you.

Comment: Sure, i just added more info on `round` and `quantize`

Comment: display initial dataframe and final you want please.....

Comment: pandas has no support for `decimal.Decimal` objects. You'll have to resort to iterating using smothing like `.apply` or `df.itertuples()`

Comment: thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga i used `applymap` in the end. See edit :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since pandas has no quantize method i used the following to solve the problem:

```
out.applymap(lambda x: x.quantize(dc.Decimal('1.00')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding a bit on the answer by [@Juanito](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54774317/1810559)

With my data I got an `InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]`

This seems to be because my input data has more than the default precision of 28:

`gdf_temp['latitude'][0]`

Decimal('44.5001088968049742788934963755309581756591796875')

This worked:

```
getcontext().prec = 64

gdf_temp['longitude'] = gdf_temp['longitude'].apply(Decimal)
gdf_temp['latitude'] = gdf_temp['latitude'].apply(Decimal)

gdf_temp['longitude'] = gdf_temp['longitude'].apply((lambda x: x.quantize(Decimal('1.00000'))))
gdf_temp['latitude'] = gdf_temp['latitude'].apply((lambda x: x.quantize(Decimal('1.00000'))))

gdf_temp['latitude'][0]
```

Decimal('44.50011')

Comment: thanks for the example applying to a df column. quantize is interesting (a little confusing) because the dtype of the column is still an object but you can use it for calculations.

Comment: calculations w/ ints but not floats..?!

Answer (score 0):

To round your decimal to 2 significant figures for example:

`round(df['yourSeries'].astype('float'), 2)`

Or if you just want an int:

`round(df['yourSeries'].astype('float'))`