# Cassandra Decimal Precision Issues

Tags: python, database, cassandra, decimal, cql

I've been storing some currency in Cassandra as decimal types, and I've discovered that they're not coming out as precisely as entered. This is normally OK, however there are times I want the precision (2-decimal places). I've attempted to add precision syntax to all of my code (create table, select, insert), and all of it fails with syntax errors. I feel like it's more efficient to do the rounding on database call rather than in a Pandas DataFrame, so I'm seeing if anyone has a solution. I'm trying the syntaxes in both cqlsh and Python.

cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.2 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4

Tried doing it on the table column:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable (
    myid text,
    price decimal(14,2),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line XXXXX no viable alternative at input '(' (... [decimal](...):>
```

I saw a comment that Cassandra does not allow precision in table definitions, so fine, moving on.

Tried to do it on SELECT:

```
SELECT myid, cast(price as Decimal(14,2)) FROM myTable;

Syntax Exception: mismatched input '(' expecting ')' (...myid, cast(price as Decimal[(]...)
```

I will skip the insert because the errors are redundant, and also the values in the DataFrame are of the correct precision when entered. The table storage and selection is where it gets wonky.

The SELECT is failing because Decimal to Decimal can't be cast:
http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/functions.html

If I can't specify precision in the table semantics, and I can't store it as decimal and cast it with proper precision, I suppose I am forced to:

- store in double and cast on select, OR
- programmatically round my DataFrame after it is returned?

**Edit:**

For completeness, this is one solution that works, though I'd prefer the most efficient solution, which I think would be rounding at the data fetch level. There are no precision modifiers in any CQL, using decimal type for price column. Solution adapted from ([Decimal class rounding in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54773447/decimal-class-rounding-in-pandas)) since df.round() doesn't work on Python Decimal.

```
<set pandas row factory>
df = dbConnection.execute('SELECT myid, price FROM myTable')._current_rows
df[['price']] = df[['price']].applymap(lambda x: x.quantize(decimal.Decimal('.01')))
```

Comment: one bad way to handle issue first caste into double and then cast decimal

Answer (score 2):

CQL in contrast to SQL databases doesn't allow to customize decimal precision, etc., so you just need to use `decimal`. The data that you receive back in `cqlsh` are formatted by `cqlsh` itself - in default configuration it just calls `str` on the instance of Python's `Decimal` type (see [the code](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/pylib/cqlshlib/formatting.py#L257)). It may call another formatter if decimal separator is set to value different from `.`, or if thousands separator is set.

But I would suggest not to rely on the `cqlsh` implementation, and use driver directly, and format received `decimal` value as you want.