# python json float with leading zeros

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

How to use python (3.5) json standard library to print floats with trailing zeros?

```
import json
to_be_serialized = {'something': 0.020}
print(json.dumps(to_be_serialized))
{"something": 0.02}  # desired output: {"something": 0.020}
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447287/format-floats-with-standard-json-module/5574182#5574182) but unfortunately without desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I was forced to use non-standard python library `simplejson`. (cause `json` package is not supporting decimals)

```
import simplejson as json
from decimal import Decimal

to_be_serialized = {'something': Decimal('0.020').quantize(Decimal('.0001'))}
print(json.dumps(to_be_serialized))
```

I was unable to find a way to do this with standard `json` library, but at least it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Floats aren't designed to hold that kind of information. 0.020 and 0.02 are identical.

You can however manually set the number of decimals:

```
import json
test = 0.020
print(json.dumps({'test': '{:.3f}'.format(test)}))
```

will print

```
{"test": "0.020"}
```

Note that a) this is now a string and no longer a float and b) that the `{:.3f}` part specifically sets the number of decimals to three.

Comment: b) is ok for me, a) not :(

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to achieve? Why do you need the trailing zeros?

Comment: those are just the requirements