# How does pandas.to_json switch between fixed point and exponential notation?

Tags: python, json, pandas, floating-point

I am playing with pandas to_json method and cannot quite understand its behaviour.import json

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

FILENAME = 'test.json'

df = pd.DataFrame({6.0: [1.0e3, 1.7e42, 2.0e-4, 1.7e-7], 
                   50.0: [1.034, 1.3e-42, 1.2e17, 0.1]}, 
                  index=[75.0, 19.0, 84.0, 12.0])

df.to_json(FILENAME, double_precision=2)

with open(FILENAME, 'r') as jsonfile:
    jsondata = json.load(jsonfile)
print(json.dumps(jsondata, indent=4))
```

This prints some numbers in fixed point, and some numbers in exponential notation.

```json
{
    "6.0": {
        "75.0": 1000.0,
        "19.0": 1.7e+42,
        "84.0": 0.0,
        "12.0": 0.0
    },
    "50.0": {
        "75.0": 1.03,
        "19.0": 1.3e-42,
        "84.0": 1.2e+17,
        "12.0": 0.1
    }
}
```

In particular I cannot get the value at `6.0 - 12.0` to be printed in exponential notation. It is always saved as 0.0, while it really screws up the numerics.

Is there a way to enforce exponential notation for `pd.to_json`?

Why is it treating `1.7e-7` differently from `1.3e-42`?

The boundary seems to lie between the values of exponent of `e-15` and `e-16`. That is `1.7e-15` would be exported as `0.0` while `1.7e-16` would be exported as `1.7e-16`. This probably has something to do with the `np.float64` representation.

This is really a striking example as it shows that `to_json` does not preserve monotonicity.

```py
xf = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.0e-15, 1.0e-16]})
xf.to_json('data.json')
with open('data.json', 'r') as jsonfile:
    jsondata = json.load(jsonfile)
print(json.dumps(jsondata, indent=4))
```

would print

```json
{
    "a": {
        "0": 0.0,
        "1": 1e-16
    }
}
```

The value in row 1 is now greater than the value in row 0.

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447287/format-floats-with-standard-json-module.  It's got some old information, but it explains the issues.  I don't think anything has really changed.